# How to conditionally implement an interface for a generic class in java

Tags: java, generics

I have a container class:

```java
class Container<T> {
    private T content;

    //other fields and methods
}
```

I would like `Container<T>` to implement `Comparable<Container<T>>` but this would only make sense when `T` implements `Comparable<? super T>`. I don't want to put this bound on `T`, because `Container` needs to also work for the types that don't implement `Comparable`.

The best I could think of is to change `content` to `protected` and add a subclass:

```java
class ComparableContainer<T extends Comparable<? super T>> extends Container<T>
        implements Comparable<ComparableContainer<T>> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ComparableContainer<T> other) {
        return this.content.compareTo(other.content);
    }
}
```

But for this to be useful there needs to be a way to safely cast `Container<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` into `ComparableContainer<T>`.

Additionally, making `content` `protected` gives access to it to other subclasses of `Container`, which is not desirable.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem, what exactly you are trying to achieve? `Container<T>` implementing `Comparable <Container<T>>` does not put any restrictions to `T`, it sounds more like a business logic limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using composition instead of inheritance to solve this case:

```
static <E extends Comparable<E>, C extends Container<E>> Comparator<C> createComparator() { ... }
```

Now you can `Collections.sort(listOfComparableContainers, createComparator())`

Or if you really need a `Comparable<Container<T>>` from a `Container<Comparable<T>>`, you can make a wrapper function:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> Comparable<Container<T>> comparableWrapper(Container<T> container) { ... }
```

Then you'll need to wrap each element in the list before you can sort them. But it's better than forcing all other places in your application to create a `ComparableContainer` if `T` is `Comparable`, and a normal `Container` if it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

> *"... I would like `Container<T>` to implement `Comparable<Container<T>>` but this would only make sense when `T` implements `Comparable<? super T>`. ..."*

Typically, in *Java*, when writing *class* *objects*, it's more productive to be as specific as possible.
And, to use a *[type-parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)* to only broaden the constraint.

Start with an *[interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)*, or an *[abstract class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)*, and create a *sub-class* for each application.

```java
abstract class Container<T> {
    T content;
}

class BasicContainer<T> extends Container<T> {

}

class ComparableContainer<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Container<T> implements Comparable<Container<T>> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Container<T> o) {
        if (content == null) return o.content == null ? 0 : 1;
        if (o.content == null) return -1;
        return content.compareTo(o.content);
    }
}
```